# Trying to cleanup a Nested Promise Chain in Node.js with Bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

Here is what my code looks like:

```
                return request.app.currentProject().then(function(project) {
                    return project.prs().query({
                        where: {id: request.params.prId}
                    }).fetchOne().then(function(pr) {
                        if (!pr) { return reply(Boom.notFound()); }

                        pr.destroy().then(function(model) {
                            return reply().code(204);
                        }).catch(function(err) {
                            return reply(Boom.badRequest(err));
                        });
                    }).catch(function(err) {
                        return reply(Boom.badRequest(err));
                    });
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    return reply(Boom.badRequest(err));
                });
```

Right now, in the code above, I have to catch each promise individually. Is there anyway to chain them so the errors bubble up without having to catch each promise individually?

**Update**

```
            return request.app.currentProject().then(function(project) {
                return project.prs().query({
                    where: {id: request.params.prId}
                }).fetchOne();
            }).then(function(pr) {
                return pr.destroy();
            }).catch(function(err) {
                return reply(Boom.badRequest(err));
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise errors bubble up automatically; you don't need to do anything.
Just remove all error handlers except at the end of the chain.

For more detailed guidelines for error handling, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I removed all of the error handling except the one at the end, but Im not seeing my error in the reply, only in the terminal do I see an error

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: That's because you're breaking the chain by not returning the promises from nested async calls.  Every time you call a function that returns a promise, you must `return` that promise to continue the chain.  You can then un-nest all of your callbacks, too.

Comment: thank you so much!!! Makes so much more sense, now! I added in my working code above

Comment: Yes; that's exactly what you want to write.